# How do I write stored procedures to update one table of one schema from another table of a different schema?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql

How can I update a table from one schema table to another schema table without importing the whole table.

Comment: This is very basic SQL.  All you need to do is use `schema.tablename` in your query.  e.g.: `Select * From dbo.Table1 T1 Join dev.Table1 DevT1 On T1.Col1 = DevT1.Col1`.  But if you're struggling with references to tables in a different schema other than the default, perhaps you shouldn't just blindly try to run an update statement in your production environment to fix the mess...

Comment: @Siyual great point. I would advise you to do a SELECT First to make sure what you are updating is exactly what you are intending. So write your update statement and then comment it out (the UPDATE part) and select what you have in your WHERE statement to make sure that's what you want to really update. Oh and if you can take a backup of the database before you do it!

Comment: Yes that a great point.  Will run it in my schema first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are asking how to write a query for different schemas.

All you need to do is prefix the table name with the schema name.

Example Schema: Cat  and Schema Dog

```
SELECT * FROM Cat.Food cf JOIN Dog.Food df on cf.sustinanceID = df.sustinanceID
```

The same concept applies to `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. Just prefix it with the schema name.